# How to get specific row in Aerospike from using aql

Tags: aerospike

When I query in Aerospike using following it works:

```
aql> select * from connekt.inapp
```

as seen below:

[image]

However to find an specific entry I am trying following query, but it does not work:

```
aql> select * from connekt.inapp where DIGEST = "viwZnPMMutuTZkPBV/PPL6hmWW0="
```

> Error: (2) AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND

[image]

How to get a specific row from Aerospike using aql.

Answer (score 4):

The digest you are seeing "AAAA....=" that was a cosmetic bug in AQL -  I believe it was fixed couple of months ago, not sure which version of TOOLS release has it. [Bug - TOOLS-746]

It is rather moot because you already know the digest - you used it in the where = "viwZn...."

BTW, do

`$aql
aql>HELP`

for info on list of commonly used AQL commands.  (Where digest= and edigest = are rarely useful in production. AQL is best used for exploring data, creating and managing Secondary Indexes, developing UDFs and Security management)

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research and going through [docs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/record_operations.html), I realised that in my case, digest is in Base64, format, so I have to query using `EDIGEST` like following:

```
aql> select * from connekt.inapp where EDIGEST = "viwZnPMMutuTZkPBV/PPL6hmWW0="
```

From  [docs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/record_operations.html):

> When providing the HEX representation of the digest (for example from
>   the server logs), use DIGEST :
>
> SELECT * FROM [.] WHERE DIGEST='DIGEST_HEX_STRING'
>
> When
>   providing the Base64 representation of the digest (for example from
>   asbackup file), use EDIGEST :
>
> SELECT * FROM [.] WHERE EDIGEST=DIGEST_B64_STRING

However when querying like this, in the result digest is `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=`, which I am not sure why is the case.

[image]